# Using Queues to uniformly sample from multiple input files

Tags: tensorflow

I have one serialized file for each class in my dataset. I would like to use queues to load up each of these files and then place them in a RandomShuffleQueue that will pull them off so I get a random mix of examples from each class. I thought this code would work.

In this example each file has 10 examples.

```py
filenames = ["a", "b", ...]

with self.test_session() as sess:
  # for each file open a queue and get that
  # queue's results. 
  strings = []
  rq = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(1000, 10, [tf.string], shapes=())
  for filename in filenames:
    q = tf.FIFOQueue(99, [tf.string], shapes=())
    q.enqueue([filename]).run()
    q.close().run()
    # read_string just pulls a string from the file
    key, out_string = input_data.read_string(q, IMAGE_SIZE, CHANNELS, LABEL_BYTES)
    strings.append(out_string)

    rq.enqueue([out_string]).run()

  rq.close().run()
  qs = rq.dequeue()
  label, image = input_data.string_to_data(qs, IMAGE_SIZE, CHANNELS, LABEL_BYTES)
  for i in range(11):
    l, im = sess.run([label, image])
    print("L: {}".format(l)
```

This works fine for 10 calls, but on the 11th it says that the queue is empty.

I believe this is due to a misunderstanding on my part of what these queues operate on. I add 10 variables to the `RandomShuffleQueue`, but each of those variables is itself pulling from a queue, so I assumed the queue would not be emptied until each of the file queues was empty.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: To start to figure this out:  Do you want to read all of the examples into memory and shuffle them, or do you want to keep feeding into the random shuffle queue from the 10 files as space frees up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer to this question will depend on how many files you have, how large they are, and how their sizes are distributed.

The immediate problem with your example is that `rq` only gets one element for each `filename in filenames`, then the queue is closed. I'm presuming that there are 10 `filenames`, since `rq.dequeue()` will consume one element of `rq` each time you call `sess.run([label, image])`. Since the queue is closed, no more elements can be added, and the 11th activation of the `rq.dequeue()` operation fails.

The general solution is that you have to create additional threads to keep running `rq.enqueue([out_string])` in a loop. TensorFlow includes a `QueueRunner` class that is designed to simplify this, and some other functions that handle common cases. The [documentation for threading and queues](http://tensorflow.org/how_tos/threading_and_queues/index.html#threading-and-queues) explains how they are used, and there is also some good information on [using queues to read from files](http://tensorflow.org/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#reading-from-files).

As to your particular problem, one way you could handle this would be to create `N` readers (for each of `N` files). You could then [`tf.pack()`](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#pack) `N` elements (one from each reader) into a batch, and use [`enqueue_many`](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#QueueBase.enqueue_many) to add a batch at a time into a [`tf.RandomShuffleQueue`](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#RandomShuffleQueue) with a sufficiently large capacity and `min_after_dequeue` to ensure that there is sufficient mixing between the classes. Calling [`dequeue_many(k)`](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#QueueBase.dequeue_many) on the `RandomShuffleQueue` would give you a batch of `k` elements sampled from each file with equal probability.

Comment: Is it possible to have more readers than available threads? I have 100 files from which I want to sample approximately equally. Can I create 100 readers in this case?