# TFRecords and record shuffling

Tags: tensorflow

My understanding is that it is good practice to shuffle training samples for each epoch so that each mini-batch contains a nice random sample of the entire dataset. If I convert my entire data-set into a single file containing TFRecords then how is this shuffling to be achieved short of loading the entire data-set? My understanding is that there is no efficient random access to TFRecord files. So, to be specific, I am looking for guidance as to how TFRecord files are used in this scenario.

Comment: There's `shuffle_batch` which uses `RandomShuffleQueue`. It shuffles the buffered portion of the dataset, this question has more details -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33715728/using-queues-to-uniformly-sample-from-multiple-input-files

Comment: That is a helpful post but the solution he proposes still loads the entire dataset: it seems like the problem there is to make sure that the classes are equally represented in a mini-batch. If it is not practical to load the entire dataset then it seems the best approach is simply to maintain queues of filenames and load individual instances (perhaps with many threads feeding into a queue). In this scenario, TFRecord does not seem to provide much value.

Comment: @bartgras has answered this question more appropriately, with a capability offered in the new version of Tensorflow. (SEE BELOW) and upvote

Answer (score 10):

It's not - you can improve the mixing somewhat by sharding your input into multiple input data files, and then treating them [as explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34258043/getting-good-mixing-with-many-input-datafiles-in-tensorflow).

If you need anything close to "perfect" shuffling, you would need to read it into memory, but in practice for most things, you'll probably get "good enough" shuffling by just splitting into 100 or 1000 files and then using a shuffle queue that's big enough to hold 8-16 files worth of data.

I have an itch in the back of my head to write an external random shuffle queue that can spill to disk, but it's very low on my priority list -- if someone wanted to contribute one, I'm volunteering to review it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually now you don't have to worry about shuffling before saving to TFRecords. It's because (currently) recommended method to read TFRecords uses `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` which implements `.shuffle()` method.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure that's true. The shuffle() method you describe gives only local randomness (Across the the capacity of the queue), and not across the entire record.

Comment: I never said it uses entire dataset. But that also doesn't mean that the queue based shuffling isn't enough to provide necessary randomness. I saw it being used in few implementations, you can have a look at e.g. tensor2tensor repo where this method is being used.